# Is the cancellation law - group relationship a bi-implication?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In my textbook there's a theorem that says that given a group, both cancellation laws hold. But if I have a finite set such that both cancellation laws hold, does it follow that the set is a group?

Comment: @NoahSchweber but natural numbers > 7 is not finite

Comment: Sorry, missed the finiteness requirement. The answer is still no: you can break associativity. See for instance the second-to-last example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup#Examples).

Comment: I don't think this deserves a downvote and vote to close. This is a natural question to have that is difficult to make progress on unless you happen to see the right idea (at which point it essentially answers itself), and I'm not sure what additional context is being hoped for.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to construct lots of nonassociative (hence not groups!) binary operations on finite sets which are cancellative:

Fix an odd positive integer $n$. In the group $C_n$ of integers modulo $n$ under addition, "division by $2$" is total and well-defined in the sense that for all $x$ there is exactly one $y$ with $y+y=x$. This lets us define, on the set $\{0,1,...,n-1\}$, the following "average" operation: $a\star b$ is the unique $c$ such that $c+c=a+b$.

The operation $\star$ is clearly cancellative (this is a good exercise) but in general is non-associative. For example, working in $C_5$ we have $$(1\star 3)\star 4=2\star 4=3$$ but $$1\star (3\star 4)=1\star 1=1.$$

Non-associative algebraic structures are less broadly known but are widely studied still; there is, for example, quite a lot of literature on **finite *loops*** (and related structures) that you might be interested in.

Answer (score 4):

The multiplication in a group also needs to be associative, and as Noah has shown there are many non-associative binary operations, even cancellative ones. Another easy example is the operation $(a, b) \mapsto a - b$ on the cyclic group $C_n$ (constructed, for example, as the integers $\bmod n$). On the other hand, we have the following:

> **Claim:** If $G$ is a finite set and $m : G \times G \to G$ is an associative cancellative operation, then $(G, m)$ is a group; in particular, $G$ has an identity and inverses.

*Proof.* We'll write the multiplication as concatenation as usual. Let $g \in G$ be any element. Since $G$ is finite, by the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), there are positive integers $m > n$ such that $g^m = g^n$. Set $e = g^{m-n}$. We want to show that $e$ is an identity, meaning that $eh = he = h$ for any $h \in G$. To see this, we have that $g^m = g^n$ implies

$$g^n e h = g^n h$$

for any $h$, and cancelling $g^n$ gives $eh = h$; similarly for right multiplication.

Now set $g' = g^{m-n-1}$. Then $g g' = g' g = g^{m-n} = e$, so $g'$ is the inverse of $g$. Since $g$ was arbitrary, inverses exist, so $G$ is a group. $\Box$

The finiteness of $G$ is essential here for the pigeonhole argument to work, and this argument fails for infinite $G$. For example, $+ : \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is associative and cancellative but does not have inverses (or an identity depending on whether you take $\mathbb{N}$ to include $0$).